# does uncorrelation imply mean independence?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $ cov(\epsilon_i , \epsilon_j)=0$, $ E(\epsilon_i)=E(\epsilon_j)=0$ and they have the same finite variance. Can we deduce from these assumptions that $E(\epsilon_i |\epsilon_j)=0$ ? The claim is in my econometrics book, but I cannot prove it...

Comment: They are not necessarily of joint normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

No, uncorrelated variables are not necessarily independent. This is like *the* implication of a basic probability/statistics course which is known to be an implication with a false converse.

If variables $\epsilon_i$, $\epsilon_j$ are independent with zero expectation, then $\mathbb E[\epsilon_i \epsilon_j] = \mathbb E[\epsilon_i] \mathbb E[\epsilon_j] = 0$, so they are uncorrelated.

Note : are your variables $\epsilon_i$ assumed to be of some distribution? With some context (which I don't see in your question, so I can't guess), they *might* be independent.

Added : let $X$ be a uniform random variable on the interval $[-1,1]$, so that $\mathbb E[X] = 0$. Consider $Y = X^2 - \mathbb E[X^2]$, so that $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[Y] = 0$ and 
$$
\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[X^3 - \mathbb E[X^2] X ] = \mathbb E[X^3] - \mathbb E[X^2] \mathbb E[X] = 0. 
$$
because $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[X^3] = 0$ ($X^3$ is odd and $[-1,1]$ and $X$ are symmetric). We have $\mathbb E[Y|X] = Y$. (Feel free to replace $Y$ by $c Y$ to adjust the variance to that of $X$ ; it still gives you a counter example.)

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks, Patrick! I know they are not necessarily independent when they are uncorrelated.Yet my question is whether they are MEAN independent or not.

Comment: @user119758 : Do you know anything about the variables $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ other than the covariance condition and expectation conditions? Otherwise I'm pretty much convinced there are counter-examples.

Comment: $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ have the same finite variance $\sigma^2$. @Patrick

Comment: In your example W=1 almost surely hence W is independent of everything, including Z.

Comment: I added an example which fits the context of the OP. @user119758 take a look!

Comment: @Did : I know, I got it the wrong way around... anyway this was a bad example ; I removed it. I didn't do these things in a long time, memory is working at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickDaSilva ! This counterexample works!